# Using \Makelowercase in includegraphics

Tags: macros, includegraphics

I feel like this should be very simple to do but even using multiple other SE solutions I have not been able to figure it out.

I would like to pass an argument like `Evans1963` to a command that I have defined:

```
\newcommand{\placefigure}[1]{
    \begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.47\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{\MakeLowercase{#1}_results}
        \caption{\citeauthor{#1} study results}
        \label{fig:#1_results}
    \end{wrapfigure}
}
```

I need the `\MakeLowercase` in the `\includegraphics` call because even though my citation keys are in the `Evans1963` format (which I call later with `cite`), my figures are saved in the `evans1963` format.

Then I could just call:

```
\placefigure{Evans1963}
```

And both my image would be included and the citation would work correctly.

However, I get the error:

```
Missing input file '\MakeLowercase {Evans1963}_results'
```

Comment: Using windows `\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Evans1963_results}` loads `evans1963_results.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

I'm very sorry, I can't solve your problem very elegantly, I think the following code should make your project work：

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \Lowercase \str_lowercase:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\placefigure}[1]{
    \begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.47\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{\Lowercase{#1}_results}
        \caption{\citeauthor{#1} study results}
        \label{fig:#1_results}
    \end{wrapfigure}
}
```

I'm guessing your problem is here

```latex
\includegraphics{\MakeLowercase{#1}_results}
```

At first, I thought it was a problem with the macro expansion order：
So, I tried as follows

```latex
\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter{\MakeLowercase{#1}_results}
```

it still doesn't work,the macro `\MakeLowercase` is does'nt expand?

i try:

```latex
\def\a{evans1963_results}
\includegraphics{\a}
```

it is normal!
Sorry I didn't find a more feasible way, or I didn't figure out why，I hope someone can explain it！

Comment: This is indeed a good idea, and it's working.

Answer (score 3):

The `\Makelowercase` LaTeX macro uses `\lowercase` TeX primitive and this command cannot be used as an argument denoting file name. This argument is only expanded but commands like `\lowercase` cannot be processed here.

But the solution of your problem is simple. You can do `\lowercase` first and then the `\incudegraphics` is called. Instead:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{\lowercase{#1}_results}
```

use

```
\lowercase{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{#1_results}}
```

We take advantage that the words `width` and `results` are in lowercase already, they are not changed.

Comment: If the parameter contains uppercase letters, you can use ```\def\tempa{Results}，\lowercase{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{#1_\tempa}}``` ， to avoid it being expanded

Comment: ... to avoid being modified by `\lowercase` (no being expanded).

Answer (score 0):

In case `\includegraphics`' optional argument contains things that shall not be lowercased and/or some component of the filename shall not be lowercased, you can use a macro for composing the call to `\includegraphics` from several arguments whereof the first argument contains things to be lowercased:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Evans1963,
    author    = "Ex and Amp and Le",
    title     = "Example book",
    year      = "1234",
    publisher = "Example's publisher",
    address   = "Address of Example's publisher"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage[round,sort,authoryear]{natbib}

\newcommand\PassFirstAndSecondToThird[3]{#3{#1#2}}
\newcommand{\placefigure}[1]{%
    \begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.47\textwidth}%
        \centering
        \lowercase{\PassFirstAndSecondToThird{#1}}{_results}{%
          \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]%
        }%
        \caption{\citeauthor{#1} study results}%
        \label{fig:#1_results}%
    \end{wrapfigure}%
}

\begin{document}

\placefigure{Evans1963}

Text.

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

In case you insist in using `\MakeLowercase` you need to apply some crude brace hacking in order to get things out of the additional braces produced by `\MakeLowercase`—**but this is not recommendable** because `\MakeLowercase` may insert commands for producing glyphs of a font instead of characters, besides this on 8-bit engines with utf8-encoded .tex-input-files you probably may not be happy with the handling of utf8-characters outside the ASCII-range—you might be better off using `expl3's \str_lowercase:n`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Evans1963,
    author    = "Ex and Amp and Le",
    title     = "Example book",
    year      = "1234",
    publisher = "Example's publisher",
    address   = "Address of Example's publisher"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage[round,sort,authoryear]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\PassFirstAndSecondToThird[3]{#3{#1#2}}
\newcommand{\placefigure}[1]{%
    \begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.47\textwidth}%
        \centering
        \MakeLowercase{%
          \unexpanded{%
            \expandafter\@gobble\string{}%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
            \expandafter\@gobble\string}%
            \PassFirstAndSecondToThird
          }%
          {#1}%
        }{_results}{%
          \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]%
        }%
        \caption{\citeauthor{#1} study results}%
        \label{fig:#1_results}%
    \end{wrapfigure}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\placefigure{Evans1963}

Text.

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]